Safe Wallet | How to sign in to a web app without sending a transaction?
I am looking to sign into a web app that requires me to sign something in my wallet that I normally wouldn't need to spend gas for.
However, my safe app requires that I send a transaction for it, how do I sign in and sign without executing?
Edit
It looks like it was what I feared. The UI needs to support the contract wallets themselves. So if the website doesn't support it - too bad.
